# Generate XML files with swift

Tags: xml, swift

How can I create XML files "manually" using swift? Is there any library that I can use? I saw that in objc it's possible to add libxml but even with that I can't find any good documentation on it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [XMLDocument](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmldocument) to [write XML](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/WritingXML.html). For example:

```
import Foundation
let root = XMLElement(name: "root")
let xml = XMLDocument(rootElement: root)
root.addChild(XMLElement(name: "foo", stringValue:"bar"))
print(xml.xmlString)
```

Comment: just one more question, if I want on the root to add some more stuf like option how would I do? The output that I want is smth like 
<root "some option here"></root>

Comment: @Nuno See the documentation of `NSXMLElement`. The “options” are called “attributes” – there are many methods to manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But anyway I just found out that it doesn't work on IOS so I need to find another solution.

Comment: This gives me a compile error: "Use of unresolved identifier NSXMLElement"

Comment: @TimScott Are you using it in an iOS project? It's only available on OS X at the moment.

Comment: NSXMLDocument only applies to OS X (as of now). Are there any standard apis for iOS ?

Answer (score 10):

I made this new simple and lightweight XML parser for iOS in Swift - [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML)

You can use it to read XML data like this:

```
let someValue = xmlDocument["element"]["child"]["anotherChild"].value
```

or you can use it to build XML string like this:

```
let document = AEXMLDocument()
let element = document.addChild("element")
element.addChild("child")
document.xmlString // returns XML string of the entire document structure
```

NSXMLDocument works for OSX, but does not exist on iOS, so this will help in that case.

Comment: @tadija - Looks like this library is having compatibility issues with SwiftyJSON. As soon as I installed it using cocoapods the build started failing