# The best way to format data when writing to XML

Tags: xml, macos, swift2

I'd like to create a XML document like this:

```
<prefs>
    <exactmap>
        <map>
            (UCS point_1 : x =  50.0, y =  50.0)
            (UCS point_2 : x = 300.0, y = 200.0)
            (UCS point_3 : x = 200.0, y = 400.0)
            (UCS point_4 : x = 300.0, y = 300.0)
        </map>
    </exactmap>
</prefs>
```

So far my code (expression) looks like a mess:

```
let writeToXML: NSString = "<prefs>\n\t<exactmap>\n\t\t<map>\n\t\t\t//(UCS point_1 : x =  50.0, y =  50.0 )\n\t\t\t(UCS point_2 : x = 300.0, y = 200.0 )\n\t\t\t(UCS point_3 : x = 200.0, y = 400.0 )\n\t\t\t(UCS point_4 : x = 300.0, y = 300.0 )\n\t\t</map>\n\t</exactmap>\n</prefs>"
```

How to generate a XML-formatted file using Swift?

How to feed values for `X` and `Y` coordinates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate XML files with swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954702/generate-xml-files-with-swift)

Comment: My question is different at some aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML structure is wrong. How are you going to read back from the XML file? Your data has now become unstructured.

Play with the code below. It's pretty long because it's XM (sadly)

```
func xmlAttributeWithName(name: String, value: String) -> NSXMLNode {
    let node = NSXMLNode(kind: .AttributeKind)
    node.name = name
    node.stringValue = value

    return node
}

// Your data
let points = [
    (x: 50.0, y: 50.0),
    (x: 300.0, y: 200.0),
    (x: 200.0, y: 400.0),
    (x: 300.0, y: 300.0)
]

let mapElement = NSXMLElement(name: "map")
for (index, p) in points.enumerate() {
    let pointElement = NSXMLElement(name: "ucs_point")
    pointElement.attributes = [
        xmlAttributeWithName("id", value: "\(index)"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("x", value: "\(p.x)"),
        xmlAttributeWithName("y", value: "\(p.y)")
    ]

    mapElement.addChild(pointElement)
}

let exactMapElement = NSXMLElement(name: "exactmap")
exactMapElement.addChild(mapElement)

let prefsElement = NSXMLElement(name: "prefs")
prefsElement.addChild(exactMapElement)

let xmlDocument = NSXMLDocument(rootElement: prefsElement)
xmlDocument.characterEncoding = "utf-8"
xmlDocument.version = "1.0"

let xmlOptions = NSXMLNodePrettyPrint | NSXMLNodeCompactEmptyElement
let xmlString = xmlDocument.XMLStringWithOptions(xmlOptions)
try! xmlString.writeToFile("/path/to/file.xml", atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<prefs>
    <exactmap>
        <map>
            <ucs_point id="0" x="50.0" y="50.0"/>
            <ucs_point id="1" x="300.0" y="200.0"/>
            <ucs_point id="2" x="200.0" y="400.0"/>
            <ucs_point id="3" x="300.0" y="300.0"/>
        </map>
    </exactmap>
</prefs>
```